# Cannot get resourceId for pool of Azure load balancer

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

According to the resource documentation here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid

I can pass in the namespace followed by additional names depending on how deep the object is nested inside the parent resource.  In my case, I simply want the resource ID for a backend pool within a load balancer so I specify the following:

```
[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers','myLoadBalancer', 'backendAddressPools', 'myPool')]
```

This causes the following exception to be generated when deploying the template.

> Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': the type
>   'Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers' requires '1' resource name
>   argument(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be:

```
[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools','myLoadBalancer', 'myPool')]
```

reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid

check the database example

Comment: That was it!  Thank you will accept it when it allows me (you were too quick ; )